# Selecting values of a column from a join based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in T-SQL and I'm joining on a table. I need to return the value based on the start and end date. So the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN TABLE2.DATE1 < DATE2 THEN TABLE2.VALUE1
    WHEN TABLE2.DATE1 > DATE2 THEN TABLE2.VALUE2 
    END AS 'My Col' 
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

Syntactically I'm just not sure how to make this work

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: So I have a contract date of: 2017-08-31 in table2 and if this day is greater than today I need to return value 'H' from table2. If it's less than today I need to return value 'R' table2, both of these values are located in the same column. So in this case I would return value R to my column.

Comment: R 2018-06-16 Here is an 'R' datapoint

Comment: If you write up a statement that makes the table, populates it with your data, and post that in your question people will have the sample data to try and write an answer against.  More work on your part, but easy for some SQL pro to help you.

Comment: Please don't add data in the comments. The formatting renders it useless.

Comment: H 2050-01-01: Here is an 'H' datapoint

Comment: @sniperd my only thing is this query is huge. Should I just post the whole thing?

Comment: @KevinWright maybe not the whole thing.  But if you make a small example of data to demonstrate where you are stuck and post that CREATE and INSERT INTO, people can simply copy/paste that and they craft a solution.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Alright. I'll have to check that out and repost later with more details. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TABLE2.DATE1 > GETDATE() THEN TABLE2.H
             WHEN TABLE2.DATE1 < GETDATE() THEN TABLE2.R 
        END) AS MyCol
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.id = table1.id;
```